# How to change Setup.exe properties in .NET Installer

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and I made an installer, if I right click on setup.exe and click on properties, it shows wrong information for:

- Company,
- File Version,
- Product Name ,
- Product Version.

Is there any way to properly set these values?

Answer (score 2):

click on your setup project and go to your properties window. if it is not displayed, click view menu at top most part of your vs2008 and click properties window. You can see there the Manufacturer, Version, Product Name etc. Change it and then rebuild your setup project.

Comment: Don't think this answers the question: wouldn't this change the MSI properties, not the `setup.exe` properties? -1

Answer (score 1):

When you use a VisualStudio .NET setup project, the `setup.exe` part of the output does not really change when you compile. The real result of the setup project is the MSI file; this is your actual setup. The `setup.exe` is "just" there to make sure that (the correct version of) Microsoft Installer is installed on the machine before the MSI is executed by Microsoft Installer. So the properties of `setup.exe` will not change at all, except perhaps with another version of Visual Studio (or a Service Pack), no matter what you change in your setup project or how often your rebuild that setup project.